# Angular doesnt set dynamic HTML embed src attribute at second time

Tags: html, angular, pdf

I am trying to set PDF file paths dynamically to `embed` tag using `this.renderer.setAttribute(this.pdf.nativeElement, "src", ...`

**At first** I can set `embed` `src` PDF path and it displays on screen but **second time** I set for another path it doent work as expected.

Can anyone help?

Live demo link is:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kghaku

Comment: `attribute` changes are not detected by javascript. you should use property instead of attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first remove the src attribute and then apply the new one. Also, need to wrap the `setAttribute` in a  `setTimeout`, since it needs to execute after `removeAttribute`

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dd6zae)

```
 setpdf1() {
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.pdf.nativeElement, "src");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.pdf.nativeElement, "src", "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf")
    })
  }

  setpdf2() {
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.pdf.nativeElement, "src");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.pdf.nativeElement, "src", "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf")
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding:

```
  <embed #pdf src="{{ selectedSRC }}">
```

In component:

```
  selectedSRC: string;

  setpdf1(){
    this.selectedSRC = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
  }

  setpdf2(){
    this.selectedSRC = "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf";
  }
```

Comment: You can sanitize it.

Comment: I did before but didnt work, only solution is removing src from embed and assigning it again as syncronious